# MDriven | Give DLL dependency list with new framework updates

Tags: mdriven

For future releases of the MDriven Framework would it be possible to provide a list of dependencies? Similar to what we have in the Nuget package manager?

[image]

The problem is that after every MDriven update, we need to spend a good chunk of time getting the dependent packages right. We need to upgrade and downgrade until all the packages installed are of that what MDriven needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - its a bit of hassle.
Its basically the shift from Microsoft to put more into packages rather into framework that spills over to us.
Currently we provide .netStandard+.net6 nuget-packages all starting with mdriven. These packages are one MDriven assembly in one package. The old .netFramework packages we provided were a bit mixed.

The new strategy allows you to see dependencies in Nuget - and going forward into modern .net I hope it will be less of a struggle to configure all dependencies.